# Como puedo hacer para que mi jboss levante aunque la conexion a una cola halla fallado?

Tags: wildfly, websphere-mq

Entorno:
wildfly 10
MQ Series
Resource-adapter de jboss para MQ Series

La cuestión en la siguiente tengo un .ear dentro de la capeta deployments de wildfly y ahi tengo un consumidor MDB que consume mensaje de la cola MQ Series mediante el resource-adapter.

Cuando inicio el servidor y existe conexión a la cola .. todo funciona ok.
Cuando inicio el servidor y NO existe conexión a la cola .. no se hace el deploy del server ...

Lo que quiero es como puedo configurar o estructurar para que cuando inicie el servidor y las colas esten caidas .. se haga el deploy y me funcionen todos las cosas excepto las colas....

cualquier comentario es bienvenido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá les dejo la respuesta...
Esto se realiza configurando el resource-adapter con estas propiedades:
3
50000

Según documentación:

**startupRetryCount:** (Default 0)
The default number of times to try and connect a MDB on startup, if the queue manager is not running when the application server is started

**startupRetryInterval:** (Default 30 000)
The default sleep time between startup connection attempts (in milliseconds).

Así logré que el servidor de app levantara aunque la colas estuviesen sin conexión....

Saludos